# Trying combine multiple .csv files using terminal, command not found: copy. Wrong path for Homebrew Mac Catalina 10.15

Tags: macos, csv, terminal, path, homebrew

I am trying to combine multiple .csv files using a terminal on a Mac operating system Catalina 10.15.

I have all 332 CSV files in one folder called “specdata”. I have successfully loaded the correct folder in terminal.

When I try to combine the files I get an error “zsh: command not found copy”

**Sarah@JD-Salinger-2 ~ % cd /Users/Sarah/Desktop/specdata

Sarah@JD-Salinger-2 specdata % copy *.csv Combined

zsh: command not found: copy**

I have been looking online on how to add packages or commands to my terminal.

Most websites say use Homebrew. But when I download Homebrew I get a Warning that it is no in user/bin/local.

At the beginning of the download, it said it would install Homebrew at user/bin/local.

When I use the terminal to find the path for Hombrew I get the path below.

**Sarah@JD-Salinger-2 ~ % $PATH Homebrew

zsh: no such file or directory: usr/local/git/bin:local/git/bin:usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin**

When I use the finder on my mac to find Homebrew it is located in urs/local/Homebrew.

[pictures of Homebrew path using finder on my Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOptg.png)

Also every time I download an application when I use $PATH in terminal  $PATH Application it takes me to a similar path as Homebrew.

Application MacPorts

**Sarah@JD-Salinger-2 ~ % port version

Version: 2.6.4

Sarah@JD-Salinger-2 ~ % $PATH MacPorts

zsh: no such file or directory: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:usr/local/git/bin:local/git/bin:usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin**

How do I correct the path for Homebrew? Or is there another option, so I can combine my CSV files?

Thanks for the help.
Sarah

Comment: `copy` is not a standard unix command. `cp` (which is *short for* "copy") is a standard command, but it just copies individual files, it doesn't combine them. `cat` (short for "catenate") *might* do what you want... or might not, depending on the exact format of the files. `$PATH` isn't a command either; it contains a list of places to search for command executables. But from the error messages, your `PATH` is wrong; several of the directories in it are missing the leading "/" (for example, `usr/local/bin` should be `/usr/local/bin`). This problem is somewhere in one of your shell init files.

Answer (score 1):

I would just do :

```
 cat *.csv > combined.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I found cat *.csv > file name on another website. And it worked. Thanks for the help.